# composer does not install mongodb ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, composer-php

I ran: `composer require mongodb/mongodb`. But it gave me the following error :

has error:

> ```
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
> ```

I tried : `composer show -p`

Then it gave me:

```
......
ext-iconv           0         The iconv PHP extension
ext-mcrypt          0         The mcrypt PHP extension
ext-mhash           0         The mhash PHP extension
ext-mongo           1.6.12    The mongo PHP extension
ext-mysql           1.0       The mysql PHP extension
ext-mysqli          0.1       The mysqli PHP extension
......
```

Why am I getting the error?

`php -m`

```
..... 
libxml 
mbstring 
mcrypt 
mhash 
mongo 
mysql 
mysqli 
openssl 
pcntl
pcre
 PDO 
 .....
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Install the php driver `$ sudo pecl install mongodb`
2. Create the extension file `$ sudo nano /etc/php/*version*/mods-available/mongodb.ini` and write inside: **extension=mongodb.so**
3. Create a symbolic link for this file `$ sudo ln -sv /etc/php/*version*/mods-available/mongodb.ini  /etc/php/*version*/apache2/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini`
4. Create an other symbolic link for this file `$ sudo ln -sv /etc/php/*version*/mods-available/mongodb.ini  /etc/php/*version*/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini`
5. Restart apache or the server used `$ sudo service apache2 restart`

It may be necessary to reinstall jenssegers/mongodb: `$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb`

Comment: I did all the steps but still not able to connect to mongodb using php. Error is `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoDB\\Client' not found in`.

Comment: That means the extension was not properly loaded. Check if php is loading the extension first, try with the '$ php -i' command and check the mongo extension:

'MongoDB Support => enabled
Version => 1.6.10
Streams Support => enabled
SSL Support => enabled'

Comment: Works perfectly for Ubuntu 16.4

Comment: I only did this step:
create a file in: /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini

Answer (score 7):

for quick and easy, just do:

- `sudo pecl install mongodb`
- `sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, add (at bottom or wherever):

`; mongodb
extension=mongodb.so`

- `sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, add (at bottom or wherever):

`; mongodb
extension=mongodb.so`

- restart webserver for good measure (not necessary for cli): `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Composer seems to use the CLI version of php.ini.

Answer (score 4):

i'm run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

then:

```
pecl install mongodb
```

and add: `extension=mongodb.so` to bottom line of `cli/php.ini`

Comment: thanks for giving a more straight forward answer..  saves me some hair :)